# Running tor on randomly assigned open port from command line

Tags: c#, tor

I need to start the tor process from the command process and have a randomly assigned open port for said process.  After doing some research, I learned that I can use port 0 and the system will provide the desired functionality.

I am executing the following command on Windows 10:

```
tor --SocksPort 0 | more
```

While the output indicates success, the output does not tell me which port the process is running on.  What is the best way to find this information, programmatically in C#?  Here is my TorProxy class, see the comment in the StartAsync() method.

```
public class TorProxy : Proxy, IAsyncDisposable
{
    private Process process;
    private string dataDir;
    private int socks5Port;
    private string torPath;

    public TorProxy(int socks5Port, string torPath, string dataDir) : base(new Uri($"socks5://localhost:{socks5Port}"))
    {
        this.socks5Port = socks5Port;
        this.torPath = torPath;
        this.dataDir = dataDir;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
            {
                FileName = torPath,
                Arguments = $"--SocksPort {socks5Port} --DataDirectory {dataDir}"
            };
            process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
            //QUESTION: If socks5Port = 0, how do I find out what port was assigned to the process?
        });
    }


    public async Task StopAsync()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (process != null)
            {
                process.Kill(true);
                process.WaitForExit();
                if (Directory.Exists(dataDir))
                    Directory.Delete(dataDir, true);
            }
        });
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        await StopAsync();
    }
}
```

Side note:  I am aware of the TorSharp repo, but I am trying to accomplish some basic functionality without relying on a library.

Comment: Why you don't want to use TorSharp? https://github.com/joelverhagen/TorSharp

Comment: @GeorgyTarasov Please see the side note at the end of my post.  Explaining why I don't want to use TorSharp is beyond the scope of the question, while I appreciate you mentioning this library.  

Anyways, I found a potential solution, I just need to test it before posting it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found this after doing some further research, it seems to have been taken from Selenium source code.  It is working well for my use case:

```
public static int FindFreePort()
{
    int port = 0;
    Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    try
    {
        IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        socket.Bind(localEP);
        localEP = (IPEndPoint)socket.LocalEndPoint;
        port = localEP.Port;
    }
    finally
    {
        socket.Close();
    }
    return port;
}
```